# Having trouble with simple integral

Tags: integration

sorry I'm having some trouble evaluating this integral

$\frac{dv}{dt} = -k(v-gt)^2-g$ where g and k are constants

I'm assuming you just separate and integrate but I cannot seem to get it to work out.

Comment: What part of "separate and integrate" didn't work out, aside from the grammatical disparity?

Comment: I'm guessing the "separate" part, given that it's not separable...

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=v-gt$. Then $\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}+g$.
So our differential equation can be rewritten as
$$\frac{dy}{dt}+g=-ky^2-g,$$
and then  as 
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-(ky^2+2g).$$
This is a separable differential equation. We are solving
$$\frac{dy}{ky^2+2g}=-dt.$$
Integrate. We will get an arctan on the left.